# How to add new items to javascript array without over riding what is already inside the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]I have these 2 arrays declared

```
var newUnitsToGenerateObj = [];
    var newUnitsToGenerate = {
        UnitTypeID: null,
        NumOfUnits: 0
    };
```

in my UI I want the user to select the unitype and I want to pass it into thi newunitstogenerate then pass it into newunitstogenerateobj I thought this would be fairly simple like this

```
   function AddUnitsToConfig() {
        newUnitsToGenerate.UnitTypeID = $('#UnitTypeID').ejDropDownList('model.value');
        newUnitsToGenerate.NumOfUnits = $('#NumOfUnits').val();

        newUnitsToGenerateObj.push(newUnitsToGenerate);

        console.log(newUnitsToGenerateObj);
    }
```

so this function inserts the first value as expected when the button is clicked but if it is clicked a second time with new values this overrides what was in the array with the new data so I have a length of 2 as expected but they are the same values. I want to build up the newunitstogenerateobj then pass it to the server.

Comment: It's hard to tell, as you appear to be using SyncFusion, but if `#UnitTypeID` / `#NumOfUnits` corresponds to different elements each time, then you'll have elements with duplicate IDs, which is invalid markup and will confuse jQuery (resulting in the same element being targeted each time).

Comment: I cannot replicate. Note that you keep mutating the same object, so all the references to it you push into the array will have the same values. Make a new object to push into the array instead.

Comment: Jared I did what you said and it works thanks also the results the guys showed below works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mutating `newUnitsToGenerate` every time you call `AddUnitsToConfig`. You want to push a *new* object into the array with each call:

```
function AddUnitsToConfig() {
    newUnitsToGenerateObj.push({
        UnitTypeID: $('#UnitTypeID').ejDropDownList('model.value');
        NumOfUnits: $('#NumOfUnits').val();
    });

    console.log(newUnitsToGenerateObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare an empty json. inside the function

```
var newUnitsToGenerateObj = [];


function AddUnitsToConfig() {
    var newUnitsToGenerate = {};
    newUnitsToGenerate['UnitTypeID'] = $('#UnitTypeID').ejDropDownList('model.value');
    newUnitsToGenerate['NumOfUnits'] = $('#NumOfUnits').val();

    newUnitsToGenerateObj.push(newUnitsToGenerate);

    console.log(newUnitsToGenerateObj);
}
```